# cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, .net

> Error : cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Code :

```
Test obj = new Test();
obj.IsDisplay = chkDisplay.IsChecked;
```

but when I use this method to cast the property into a bool then there is no error.

```
Test obj = new Test();
obj.IsDisplay = (bool) chkDisplay.IsChecked;
```

I would like to know why I need to cast this bool to bool?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You've declared `IsChecked` as a `bool?` (`Nullable<bool>`). A nullable boolean can be either `true`, `false` or `null`. Now ask yourself: If `IsChecked` was null, then what value should be assigned to `IsDisplay` (which can only take a `true` or `false`)? The answer is that there is no correct answer. An implicit cast here could only produce hidden trouble, which is why the designers decided to only allow an explicit conversion and not an implicit one.

Answer (score 78):

As the others stated `bool?` is not equal to `bool`. `bool?` can also be `null`, see `Nullable<t>` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)).

If you know what the `null` state wants to imply, you easily can use the ?? - null-coalescing operator ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms173224.aspx)) to convert your `bool?` to `bool` without any side effects (`Exception`).

Example:

```
//Let´s say "chkDisplay.IsChecked = null" has the same meaning as "chkDisplay.IsChecked = false" for you
//Let "check" be the value of "chkDisplay.IsChecked", unless "chkDisplay.IsChecked" is null, in which case "check = false"

bool check = chkDisplay.IsChecked ?? false;
```

Comment: **Note:** The statement "use the ?? - null-coalescing operator ... to convert your bool? to bool without any side effects" is not correct - the side effect is that you're replacing `null` by `false`. You could as well do `?? true` to replace `null` by `true` - be careful here! `bool?` has a three-state logic (null, true, false), while `bool` has only two states (true, false).

Comment: If you wanted to be really picky you could do it like this: `bool check = chkDisplay.IsChecked ?? default(bool);`

Comment: "If you know what the null state wants to imply" then you know if you want `true` or `false` ... not sure why you felt the need to be picky, since the explanation was right there.

Answer (score 34):

I'm facing your question when I'm using the null check operator `?.`:

```
if (!RolesList?.Any()) //Not accepted: cannot convert bool? to bool
```

So I'm using this instead

```
if (RolesList?.Any() != true)
  //value is null or false
```

In your case you should set it like so:

```
obj.IsVisible = chkDisplayStuff.IsChecked ?? false;
```

Answer (score 17):

`bool?` is not a `bool`. It is in reality a `Nullable<bool>`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx

If you need the `bool` value then you should either cast like you are doing or call the `.Value` property on the `bool?`. There is also a `.HasValue` property you can check to make sure that it is not null.

If `IsChecked` is null, this line will error.

```
obj.IsDisplay = (bool) chkDisplay.IsChecked;
```

Answer (score 6):

`bool` is not equal to `bool?`.

`bool` can take two values, `true` and `false`.

`bool?` can take three, `true`, `false`, and `null`.

That is why they are different.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the below code to assign `false` when `IsChecked` is `null`

```
obj.IsDisplay = chkDisplay.IsChecked == true;
```

Answer (score 3):

`chkDisplay.IsChecked` is of type `bool?`. Which means it can hold values `true`, `false` and `null`.
However, `obj.IsDisplay` is of type `bool`. Which means it can only hold `true` or `false`.

Hence you have to explicitly cast it to type `bool`. However, this will still throw an exception if, the value you are trying to cast to bool is `null`.

```
bool? nullableBool = null;
bool notNullableBool = (bool)nullableBool; //This will throw InvalidOperationException
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
if (asset.IsUp ?? false)
```

Answer (score 0):

cast your nullable value to value type

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(bool? checkOffAge)
{
    if (checkOffAge != null) {
       model.CheckOffAge =(bool)checkOffAge;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add either "**== true/false**" in your if condition.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!