# Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I had delared :

`public bool Valuetype { get; set; }` in my model and  in controller used `Valuetype = s.IsValueType` which is resulting   **Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)** error .

Comment: Is this part of parameter list in your controller method? update question with controller and model code

Comment: what is type of `s`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680391/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-bool-to-bool-an-explicit-conversion-exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `s` is a `Nullable<bool>`, also written as `bool?`.  This is a value that can be a `bool` or it can be `null`.  It's not valid to simply assume that it's a `bool`; you need to test to make sure it's not `null` first, and handle the `null` appropriately if it is.

If it doesn't make sense in this context for it to be a `null` at all, then try to fix the type of `s` to be a regular `bool`.

Answer (score 0):

cast your nullable value to value type

```
public ActionResult Index(bool? checkOffAge)
{
    if (checkOffAge != null) {
       model.CheckOffAge =(bool)checkOffAge;
    }
}
```