# C#. How to assign a bool variable certain value (not true and not false)?

Tags: c#, nullable

How to assign to a bool variable certain value (not true and not false)?
I guess it can be so-called **null** state.
But I'm not sure if it's correct guess. And I have no clue how to do that.
Moreover, how to do that with possible further assignation (true/false)?

Comment: You can't. A variable of type `bool` can only hold `true` or `false`. You can have a "nullable bool", `Nullable<bool>` or `bool?` (same thing), but that is a **different type**.

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare a nullable boolean.

```
bool? x = null;
```

[.NET Docs on nullable types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/)

Answer (score 1):

Boolean is a value type, if you want to initialize it with null you can declare a nullable boolean variable, for example:

```
bool? x
```

Comment: And immediately upon declaration I've got a fail. Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 1):

*That's right*

> Types that can be set to NULL are instances of the [System.nullable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=netframework-4.7.1)
>   structure.

```
T? variable = null;
```

troubleshooting

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

[has already been answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680391/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-bool-to-bool-an-explicit-conversion-exists)